# Safari browser not running my code properly?

Tags: javascript, html, class, safari

I have the following class:

```
class Portal {

  caption = "";
  thumbnailURL = "";
  profileImgURL = "";
  mp3 = "";
  timestamp = 0.0;
  username = "";
  uid = "";
  num = 0;
  // var caption = new String();
  // var caption = "";
  // var thumbnailURL = "";
  // var profileImgURL = "";

  constructor(cap, thumb, prof, mp3, timestamp, username, uid) {
    this.caption = cap;
    this.thumbnailURL = thumb;
    this.profileImgURL = prof;
    this.mp3 = mp3;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.username = username;
    this.uid = uid;
  }
}
```

When I run this on safari brower I get the two bellow errors.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='. Expected an opening '(' before a method's parameter list.

And then despite running the script for the portal class before the main.js script I get this:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Portal

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: [Class field declarations](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) are not finalised, so I suppose Safari is not yet supporting them.

Comment: Safari doesn't [support](https://caniuse.com/#search=class%20field) [class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields).

Comment: @VLAZ How can I rewrite the class given this?

Comment: Literally just remove them. You initialise them in the constructor anyway, so the initial values are irrelevant.

Comment: @VLAZ would this work on chrome and other browsers?

Comment: Seems answer is yes

Comment: Yes, this is the current syntax anyway. Class fields are new - they aren't finished yet, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Class field declarations are not finalised](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), so I suppose Safari is not yet supporting them. – VLAZ 3 mins ago

All that is needed is:

```
class Portal {

  constructor(cap, thumb, prof, mp3, timestamp, username, uid) {
    this.caption = cap;
    this.thumbnailURL = thumb;
    this.profileImgURL = prof;
    this.mp3 = mp3;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.username = username;
    this.uid = uid;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite produce the same behavior; there is a `num` field that is initialized to 0 in the original code.

Comment: @HereticMonkey that was only bad code on my part, not necessary.